# How to access SAP Cloud Integration tool?

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-erp, sap-successfactors

I know the very basics such as it is a tool to integrate different cloud and/or on-premise systems, but what I don't understand is that where is this Integrator (hci/sci)? 
I already have an S-User, I can acces Sap Cloud Platform Cockpit (we spend most of our times in the webide creating Fiori applications). 
In Sap CP Cockpit there is a service called Cloud Integration, and it is enabled but I get a 503 – Service Unavailable page when I click on "Configure Cloud integration".

I also heard about https://cloudintegration.hana.ondemand.com tool, but I'm not familiar with it yet.

So my question is, if I have a job to integrate (e.g SuccesFactor with an ERP system on-premise) where do I go? Which platform is where I can configure the integration, etc? 
Bonus question: Is Sap Cloud Integration and Hana Cloud Integration the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

"Hana Cloud Integration" and "SAP Cloud Integration" are outdated terms for what is now called: <del>"SAP Cloud Platform Integration"</del> "SAP Integration Suite".
You can find the corresponding docu here: https://cloudplatform.sap.com/capabilities/product-info.SAP-Cloud-Platform-Integration.cceaaf2b-8ceb-4773-9044-6d8dad7a12eb.html#
On the very right side of this page is a “Contact Us” link for further help.